# Unfederating Server

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-portal

I want to unfederate my couple servers. I can't unfederate my host ArcGIS Server ( which also it's this computer ) and I can't unfederate my other server too.

I logged in Portal Admin directory as admin.[image]

Do you have any idea?

The Error text on the image:

> Error Failed to unfederate server 'ISLEM-3770.islem.com.tr:6443 (id:
>   GrVbFEv5SBByZP9B)'. java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out:
>   connect

Comment: This seems like a Tech Support issue.

Answer (score 3):

you can go in  http://portalurl/instanceportal/sharing/rest/portals/self/servers and click on the server that should be unregistered and unregister the server